# Question about react class component setState

Tags: reactjs, jsx, setstate, react-class-based-component

I don't understand this part of the code:

```
this.setState({ usernameValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);
```

If we are updating `usernameValid`, `errorMsg` in the state, what does `this.validateForm` do? Because we are writing this outside the object of `setState`.

My code:

```
class StandardForm extends Component {
      state = {
        username: "",
        usernameValid: false,
        email: "",
        emailValid: false,
        password: "",
        passwordValid: false,
        passwordConfirm: "",
        passwordConfirmValid: false,
        formValid: false,
        errorMsg: {},
      };

  validateForm = () =>{
    let { usernameValid, emailValid, passwordValid, passwordConfirmValid} = this.state;
    this.setState({
      formValid: usernameValid && emailValid && passwordValid && passwordConfirmValid
    })
  }

  validateUsername = () => {
    const { username } = this.state;
    let usernameValid = true;
    let errorMsg = { ...this.state.errorMsg };

    if (username.length < 6 || username.length > 16) {
      usernameValid = false;
      errorMsg.username = "Username should be between 6 and 15 characters";
    }
    this.setState({ usernameValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);
  };

  validateEmail = () => {
    const { email } = this.state;
    let emailValid = true;
    let errorMsg = { ...this.state.errorMsg };

    if (!/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email)) {
      emailValid = false;
      errorMsg.email = "Invalid email format";
    }

    this.setState({ emailValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);
  };

  validatePassword = () =>{
    const { password } = this.state;
    let passwordValid = true;
    let errorMsg = {...this.state.errorMsg}

    if(password.length < 8){
    let passwordValid = false;
      errorMsg.password = "Password should have at least 8 characters"
    }

    this.state({passwordValid, errorMsg})
  }

  confirmPassword  = () =>{
    const { confirmPassword, password } = this.state.confirmPassword
    let passwordConfirmValid = true; 
    let errorMsg = {...this.state.errorMsg}

    if(password !== confirmPassword){
    let passwordConfirmValid = false; 
        errorMsg.passwordConfirm = "Password do not match"
    }

    this.state({passwordConfirmValid, errorMsg})
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class-based component's `setState` lifecycle function can take a second argument callback function that is called *after* the state is updated.

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> ```
> setState(updater, [callback])
> ```

It was commonly used to do something simple like log the updated state.

```
this.setState({ value }, () => console.log('new value', this.state.value);
```

I think generally it should be avoided and if you need to issue any side-effects like validating form data then a regular component lifecycle method should be used. [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) handles updated state or props.

From the docs

> The second parameter to `setState()` is an optional callback function
> that will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is
> re-rendered. Generally we recommend using `componentDidUpdate()` for
> such logic instead.

In your case with `this.setState({ usernameValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);` the `validateForm` function reference is passed as a callback and is invoked after state is updated.